# How to make a sum_to program?

Tags: python, python-3.3

sum_to(n) returns the sum of all integer numbers up to and including n. So sum_to(10) would be 1+2+3...+10 which would return the value 55.

I tried this but it didn't give me any output.

```
def sum_to(n):
    a= 0
    for x in range(n):
        a = x + 1
    return a 

sum_to(10)
```

Comment: If this is for a practical application, use the formula 1+2+..+n = n(n+1)/2 instead. That's a lot faster than your loop.

Comment: It was actually an exercise that I was asked to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call a function with a return value that return value is not displayed unless you print it, so you need to do this `print(sum_to(10))`. Also your code has a bug in it; you need to accumulate `a` instead of assigning directly to it: `a += x+1`.

Of course, this is not a good way to calculate a sum from 1 to 10, since there's a well known formula that will give you the number directly:

```
def sum_to(n) :
  return n*(n+1)//2
```

Comment: Like this answer much better than others': fast, elegant, mathematically proven ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems here:

1. You aren't seeing any results because you need to print them.  Put the function call in [`print`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print):

   ```
   print(sum_to(10))
   ```
2. Your code needs to have `a += x + 1` so that the value of `a` is updated with each iteration of the for-loop.  Otherwise, the output of `sum_to(n)` will always be `n`.

---

However, you can accomplish this task a lot easier with the [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#sum) and [`range`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#func-range) built-ins:

```
>>> def sum_to(n):
...     return sum(range(n+1))
...
>>> print(sum_to(10))
55
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

why not do both?

```
print(sum(range(1,11)))
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you should write a = a + x + 1, and also, you need to print the result if you want to see the result on the console.